# What is the probability of getting 3 Gargantuars in the same row(PvZ)?

Tags: probability

[image: game setup]

In plants vs zombies there is a mini game called Vase Breaker where you break a vase to reveal zombies or plants. At the point of the game I am there are 3 Gargantuars(giant zombies) per 7x5 set of vases. I am trying to determine the probability that all 3 of these giants are in one row. The green vases always contain plants so the giants cannot be within them, feel free to ignore them(I did)

My best effort is 3/35 * 2/34 * 1/33 * (7 choose 3)

The probability of getting all three consecutively multiplied by the combinations they could take

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: There are $3$ rows without green vases and you choose one of them ${3 \choose 1}$ and then multiply by ${7 \choose 3}$, $3$ vases of out of $7$ where giants are.  Then there are two rows with green vases. Now choose one of the rows and choose three of the six vases in the chosen row where giants are. Finally the denominator should be ${33 \choose 3}$

Comment: Makes total sense. Thanks!